# Need to capture caller's numerical inputs made on their phone dialpad

Tags: voip, twilio, voicemail

I need a voicemail box where callers can listen to instructions, and then enter their 7 digit response using their phone's dial pad (land line or mobile).  I need to be able to capture and record their numerical responses. This sounds low tech and something that companies have been using to automate customer service for a long time (ie. "press 1 for English"), but I can't find anything that will allow me to capture those numerical inputs to look at after the call.  If there's something that's off the shelf, that would be best, otherwise, something like twilio?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Twilio can do this for you using our [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb.  You can configure Gather using its attributes to accept a max of 7 digits.

```
<Gather numDigits="7" action="http://example.com/handleInput" />
```

Once the user enters the 7th digit, we will make an HTTP request to the URL you set in the *action* parameter, passing along the specific digits the user entered.

Hope that helps.